# How is bodily complexion determined from the horoscope of the native?

Tags: astrology, body, horoscopes

I was reading in an Astrology related magazine, that it is determined from the exalted planets.

So, we need to check which planet is exalted in the chart and the complexion is determined from the complexion which that planet indicates. (so if Venus or Moon is exalted it indicates a fair complexion but if Saturn is exalted then that indicates a dark complexion).

In case, when two or more planets are exalted, then "which one is most exalted" determines the complexion.

- Is this calculation correct? If not how is the complexion of the native determined from his/her chart?

Note that every horoscope chart clearly mentions about the bodily complexion of the native.

Comment: Considering this calculation correct, how will it apply for a person born in Africa? If Venus is exalted, will he become fair?

Comment: Every race also has a horoscope just like every native has one. For an  African his race's horoscope's features predominate over his own  horoscope. For some races the features of the race are extremely dominant. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: So, you mean to say Hindu astrology doesn't apply to Non Hindu and applies to Hindu only? There are only nine planets and this astrology is true. Isn't it? E.g According to HIndu belief, There is only one Yama Dharma Raja and he punishes all creatures irrespective of country they are born. If race features are dominant, how does astrology features  affect the complexion? Are they not effective all the time?

Comment: Where did I say that? The Hindu astrology applies to the African race as well.. When that race was created the positions of the planets were probably such which indicated a dark complexion. And that feature of the race dominates the individual horoscopes features. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @Sarvabhouma so even if the individual horoscope of an African indicates that he will have a fair complexion in reality that won't be the case because the race's horoscopic features override the features of the individual horoscopes. For some races (like Chinese etc and others) this thing is noticed but that does not mean horoscope does not have the clue to the bodily complexion. It can be calculated from the chart.

Comment: Does this mean when Krishna, Vyasa, Draupadi, etc. were born when Saturn was exalted? If not, this so-called connection between astrology and complexion has no meaning.

Comment: I am asking a Q here.. I am not asserting anything .. @sv. There is a definite method of computing body complexion from the chart.. every chart has this in the basic info.. I am simply looking for that method.. What I read in that Mag mite not be true.. Moreover, it's not only Saturn that indicates a dark complexion... Mercury, Rahu, Ketu also indicate dark complexion.. Also I do not think the calculation will be this much simplistic..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get hint of the complexion from Atmakarak in Navmansha. From Jaimini Sutras,

> swAmsavasadgowra neela pitadivarnAh 
>     The color or complexion of the person, yellow, dark, golden or white must be predicted from the nature of Navamansha occupied by the AtmakAraka. J.Su. Ch 1. Pada 4, Sutra 42

Similarly, complexion of spouse can also be predicted looking at other configurations.

Comment: That means we need to chk  in which Rasi the Atmakaraka is placed in the Navamsa chart?

Comment: Yes @Rickross. .

Answer (score 0):

Exaltation, debilitation are used to evaluate the strength of planets, not colors.

for skin color

black,blue color = saturn; 
grey, brown color = rahu;
white color = venus, moon;
yellow color = jupiter;
red, pink color = Sun; 
red, reddish brown = Mars;
mixed colors = Mercury (blending, mutliplicity), ketu (mixing)

Look for 1st house and 2nd house.
1st house is for entire body;
2nd house is for face;
3rd house is for arms;
4th house is for chest;
etc.

Comment: Well arms,chest face will all be fair only for a fair person .. so are you saying the lord of the Lagna is the only deciding factor? I don't think it is the case.. Also it will be better if you add some quotes from Jyotisha texts.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange. You should cite some sources and add some explanation. Visit [help]

Comment: Are there any sources/verses in vedic texts for jobs like telephone operator, electric engineer, computer programmer, content writer in websites, and many new jobs, businesses, like mobile mechanic, chip manufacturing engineer, etc ?
Everything was not written in vedic texts. It is the astrologers responsibility to develop the science. Have we not seen a scientist Lahiri who developed a new ayanamsa?  
I came here to help answer queries. If you decide to delete all of my posts, I don't have any objection. You May always most welcome. I am not the sufferer. Your wish. please go ahead.

Comment: I am not asking references from Vedic texts.. You must have learnt all this from some Texts.. like say B.V. Raman's book or any other.. You can cite any such books.. @Light

Comment: I don't have BV Raman's books or any other. I use to prepare personal notes and follow it. Sorry.